# In wpgeodirectory how to make a lightweight page for store owners

Tags: wordpress

Buddypress is too heavy for my webpage. Also I need a page where the user can do the following actions

- Private messaging
  and
- if he is subscriber
  A link to send an email to upgrade the user to contributor
- else if he is contributor

  - Link to add place or event
  - Manage own places and events
  - Manage own lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. Install "Front end PM" plugin for private messaging (FEP)

b. Make a page "For Store's owners" and add the following shortcodes

```
    [gd_login_box]
    [front-end-pm]
```

c. Go in FEP settings and in the first one at GENERAL->Front End PM Page select "For Store's owners"

d. Add in styles.css

```
    #fep-wrapper {
       margin-top:30px;
    }

    #fep-content input[type=text]{
        width: 100% !important;
    }

    #fep-notification-bar {
        margin-top:250px;
        right:0;
        width:unset !important;
    }
```

e. Make to send always to "admin" recipient plugins\front-end-pm\includes\class-fep-form.php lines 36 and 40

```
    Replace

        'placeholder' => __( 'Name of the receipent.', 'front-end-pm' ),
        'value' => '',
    with 
        'placeholder' => 'my_site_admin',
        'value' => 'my_site_admin',
```

where 'my_site_admin' is the username of the admin of your site

f. Make the button to upgrade user from subscriber to contributor and do not allow to add listing if he is subscriber. In       plugins\geodirectory\geodirectory-functions\general_functions.php

```
    At Line 3349 Add this

    $is_subscriber = user_can( $current_user, "subscriber" );
    if ( $is_subscriber ) {
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<br />";
        echo __("You can not add listings because you are a simple subscriber. Press the following to be able to add your store","wpgeodirectory");
        echo "<br />";

        echo '<a href="'. site_url() . '/upgrade-contact-form/">'.__("I am a Store owner or Affiliate","wpgeodirectory").'</a>';
    }
```

do not allow to put listing if he is subscriber at L3388 replace

```
if ( ! empty( $show_add_listing_post_types_main_nav )) {        

    with

if ( ! empty( $show_add_listing_post_types_main_nav ) && !$is_subscriber) {
```

g. Make a  Contact form 7 with name "Upgrade contact form" with

```
        <label> Your Name (required)
        [text* your-name default:user_display_name] </label>

        <label> Your Email (required)
            [email* your-email default:user_email] </label>

        <label> Subject
            [text your-subject "Upgrade me to a Store Owner"] </label>

        <label> Your Message
            [textarea your-message "I am a subscriber and I want to be able to add my own store" ] </label>

        [submit "Send"]
```

h. Make a page "Upgrade contact form" and add the form by copy pasting the following

```
    [contact-form-7 id="553" title="Upgrade contact form"]
```

where id the id of your form